# OpenTracing, Spring Cloud Stream and Solace

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace, jaeger, opentracing

I just started using OpenTracing with the Jaeger Cloud starter. For this I added the folllowing dependency to my project:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

The *io.opentracing.contrib.spring.integration.messaging.OpenTracingChannelInterceptor* of the *opentracing-spring-messaging* project adds the Scope (ThreadLocalScope) to the message header.

The Solace binder output message handler only supports header values that are instances of Serializable.
So it doesn't work out of the box.
I implemented an aspect around this message handler that looks like this (just parts of it):

```
  final MessageTextMap messageTextMap = new MessageTextMap(message);
  tracer.inject(span.context(), Builtin.TEXT_MAP, messageTextMap);
  messageTextMap.addHeader(OpenTracingChannelInterceptor.class.getName() + ".SCOPE", ""); // with this I'm removing the ThreadLocalScope
```

With this hack it works.
What would be a proper way to avoid this hack?

Another implementation of TextMap? Which one?

Update:

I found a way, but I'm not sure this is the right way:

```
public class SolaceMessageTextMap<T> implements TextMap {

private final MessageTextMap<T> delegate;

public SolaceMessageTextMap(final Message<T> message) {
    final Message<T> filteredMessage = filteredMessage(message);
    delegate = new MessageTextMap<>(filteredMessage);
}

@Override
public Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator() {
    return delegate.iterator();
}

@Override
public void put(final String key, String value) {
    delegate.put(key, value);
}

public Message<T> getMessage() {
    return delegate.getMessage();
}

private Message<T> filteredMessage(final Message<T> message) {
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
            .copyHeaders(filteredHeaders(message.getHeaders()))
            .build();
}

private Map<String, Object> filteredHeaders(final MessageHeaders headers) {
    return headers.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> isValid(entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}

private boolean isValid(final Object value) {
    return value instanceof Serializable;
}
```

}